# How to check thread before closing program?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Well, I have a main thread and one more additional. Now I need to check additional thread before closing the program and if it's running - ask 'terminate it or not', else - just close the app.

1st edit:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculation.IsAlive)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

How to close app. in 'else' part? I think it's so easy but I can not find out it))

Comment: Sounds reasonable. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.IsAlive` flag  will do the trick.

```
   var t=new Thread(() => { });
            if (t.IsAlive)
            {
                //thread is still alive
                //true if this thread has been started and has not terminated normally or aborted;
            }
            else
            {
                //not alive
                //otherwise, false.
            }
```

Comment: If I did not call (.Start()) my additional thread, I guess, it'll not work, right?

Comment: Before you leave the execution ( UI thread) , you can check the status of your additional thread on whether or not the additional thread is still doing its job or not. If it still doing its job then  you can wait until it finishes (spinning with some timeout) or allow the main thread to complete is flow of execution.

Comment: It's really hard to nail down any issue without seeing the code. But to answer it, Yes. You must start it. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx.                         Otherwise, google it for Foreground and Background Threads and definitely you will get lot of samples on how to implement

Answer (score 3):

Check `Thread.IsAlive()` to see if the thread is still running.